# JPA The state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I need assistance in troubleshooting a relationship / query with EclipseLink 2.5.x provider.

The relationship from ThreePhaseMotorInput to ValidationMessage  is supposed to be a uni-directional OneToMany, i.e. each motor can have 0..n messages and in Java object graph ValidationMessage does not have a reference back to ThreePhaseMotorInput.

I am getting an error that JPA can't find the attributes that are part of the ValidationMessage class when accessed via ThreePhaseMotor.  (See error text below)

Thanks for thinking about my question!

**Query**

```
select msg.validationMsg, COUNT(m.id) from ThreePhaseMotorInput AS m JOIN m.valMessages AS msg GROUP BY msg.validationMsg
```

**Error**

```
 org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select msg.validationMsg, COUNT(m.id) from ThreePhaseMotorInput AS m JOIN m.valMessages AS msg GROUP BY msg.validationMsg]. 
[7, 24] The state field path 'msg.validationMsg' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[71, 84] The collection-valued path 'm.valMessages' cannot be resolved to a valid association field.
[119, 136] The state field path 'msg.validationMsg' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

**ThreePhaseMotorInput** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "three_phase_motor_input")
public class ThreePhaseMotorInput implements IThreePhaseMotorInput, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8084370807289186987L;
    @Transient
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private Integer status;
    @Transient
    private Integer numMessages;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, targetEntity = UnapprovedThreePhaseMotor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unapproved_id")
    private IThreePhaseMotor unapprovedMotor;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, targetEntity = ApprovedThreePhaseMotor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "approved_id")
    private IThreePhaseMotor approvedMotor;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType  .ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = ValidationMessage.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "input_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
    private List<IValidationMessage> valMessages;
```

**ValidationMessage** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "validation_message")
public class ValidationMessage implements Serializable, IValidationMessage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8765213112015434057L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "record_id")
    private Long recordId;
    @Column(name = "field_name")
    private String fieldName;
    @Column(name = "validation_msg")
    private String validationMsg;
    private Integer status;
    @Column(name = "fail_field")
    private String failField;
    @Column(name = "error_source")
    private Integer errorSource;
```

Comment: You have a problem in a query, probably a named query. Could you show us the query with the problem (is it this one: `[select m.approvedMotor, m.valMessages, m.valMessages.validationMsg...`)? Is that a named query or a native query?

Comment: I split out the query in the message.  It is a named query.

Comment: I updated the question with the revised query per your answer below and the error messages.  It can't seem to get to the ValidationMessage class through m.valMessages.

Comment: OK.  Got it corrected and marked your answer as accepted.  THANKS!!

Comment: I marked Andrei's answer as accpeted, upvoted both and will award the bounty in 22 hours when SO allows me to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the following query: `select m.approvedMotor, m.valMessages, m.valMessages.validationMsg, count(m.valMessages.id) from  ThreePhaseMotorInput m group by m.valMessages.validationMsg`.

That query should be a JPQL query, i.e a query where you specify entities and their Java properties. Also you must use `JOIN`s if you want to jump to another entity's properties: `m.valMessages.validationMsg` is not correct, but `INNER JOIN m.valMessages msg GROUP BY msg` is correct.

So try the following query:

```
select m, COUNT(msg) from ThreePhaseMotorInput AS m LEFT JOIN m.valMessages AS msg GROUP BY msg.validationMsg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a path expression with a Collection value association.

The documentation says: [JPQL Path Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_path)

> It is syntactically illegal to compose a path expression from a path expression that evaluates to a collection.

In your query, `m.valMessages` is illegal because it references a collection of ValidationMessages.

In the other hand, `m.approvedMotor` is legal because it is a single value association.

As suggested in Andrei response, you need to modify your query to add another path expression:

```
select msg.validationMsg, COUNT(m.id) from ThreePhaseMotorInput m JOIN m.valMessages msg GROUP BY msg.validationMsg
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use JOINs if you want to jump to another entity's properties. try the following JPQL query

```
select m, COUNT(msg) from ThreePhaseMotorInput AS m LEFT JOIN m.valMessages AS msg GROUP BY msg.validationMsg
```